# Null Pointer Exception in GeoPoint

Tags: java, android

What's wrong with the below code. It is throwing Null Pointer Exception on this line (`location.setLatitude(latitude);`). I am trying to make a circle as soon as the application is started so that is the reason I am passing location object from my `onCreate` method.

```
private Location location;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            0, 
            0, 
            locationListener);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);

    GeoPoint initialPoint = new GeoPoint( (int) (36.778261* 1E6), (int) (-119.417932 * 1E6));
    double latitude = initialPoint .getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
    double longitude = initialPoint .getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;

    location.setLatitude(latitude);
    location.setLongitude(longitude);
    locationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
}
```

Below is the class which take care of LocationUpdate.

```
private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    MapOverlay mapOverlay;

    public GPSLocationListener(MapView mapView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            mapController.animateTo(point);
            mapController.setZoom(15);

            if (mapOverlay == null) {
                mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this,android.R.drawable.star_on);
                List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
            }
            mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
            mapView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be of great help.

**UPDATE:-**

After making changes I am getting

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

Below is my code where I made changes.

```
GeoPoint initialPoint = new GeoPoint( (int) (36.778261), (int) (-119.417932));
double latitude = initialPoint .getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
double longitude = initialPoint .getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;

this.location = new Location("TechGeeky Randomly Initialized");
location.setLatitude(latitude);
location.setLongitude(longitude);
locationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Comment: You are not passing any location object in this piece of code. Do you set location somewhere else? If not, it's clear why location == null. Maybe you just forgot to ask the LocationManager for the last known location and set location to it?

Comment: `location` is never init in given code section. Initialize it.

Comment: I have added more info in the code in my question. I am not sure I totally understand what you guys said. My Goal is to draw a Circle once the application is started, so that is the reason I am passing initial location from the `onCreate method`. Can anyone explain me from the code point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do this is not fetch the last known location from `LocationManager` but instead start with a location that you defined yourself (e.g a random one) in `onCreate()`. To achieve this, simply create a new [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) object like so:

```
this.location = new Location("TechGeeky Randomly Initialized");
```

Do this instantiation before these lines in order to avoid the Exception:

```
location.setLatitude(latitude);
location.setLongitude(longitude);
locationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
```

Comment: Thanks Tobold, that's what I need. But after making changes in the code. It is givng `IndexOutOfBoundsException` Can you take a look why it is happening? I have updated my question.

Comment: @TechGeeky Where is the Exception thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Intialize Location object using this code:-

If You Want get location using Mobile Network Put this code in onCreate

```
Location location=null;  
location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

If You Want get location using GPS  Put this code in onCreate

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: I tried this just now but it is not drawing any circle on any location. It looks like the location is NULL. Is there any way I can draw a circle by passing some random location in the onCreate() method itself. I have update my code in the question to give the clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

You have instantiated location object. Where did you create object to location. Please create object to location using:

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

or

pass location object to method as argument and check null condition.